# Problem with horizontal centering 2d element on Android in Spark AR through Instagram Camera

Tags: android, coordinates, spark-ar-studio

Since update v95 and the new coordinate system in Spark AR Studio, there seems to be a bug with fullscreen canvas on Android device.

When I put a simple 2d square element in a fullscreen canvas in camera space (Rectangle of size 100x100) at position `0,0` (which should be top left of the screen), it appears cut on any android devices, but correctly on ios devices. Moreover, it works in Facebook Camera, but not Instagram Camera.

It does the same result on top right corner (not cut but not well placed), as if the canvas was not well placed to fit the screen of android devices.

Result on Instagram Camera : (not working, square appears cut)
[image: Badly appears in Instagram Camera]

Correct Result on Facebook Camera :
[image: Correctly appears in Facebook Camera]

Is there anything I can do to fix it ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but did you use the pin controls to pin to top left?

Comment: @MarkKnol No stupid question :) Yes I am using it and tried different configurations without success